# Stringing multiple jQuery nextAll() functions together in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a page with mutliple s and I want to be able to run functions on different child elements to those individual h2s when they are clicked. Here's the coffeescript I have:

```
$("h2").click ->
  $(@).nextAll('#data').toggle("blind")
  $(@).nextAll('.c1').toggleClass("minsize")
  $(@).nextAll("#datacontainer").toggleClass("datacontainer")
  $(@).addClass("showtext")
```

Here's the relevant HTML structure I'm using (in haml, this is part of a Rails app):

```
#clipboard
%ul.clipmenu
    -@snapshots.each do |snapshot|
        %li.clip.c1[snapshot]
            = image_tag snapshot.attachment.url
            #datacontainer.c1
                %h2= snapshot.default_name
                #data.c1{:style => "display:none"}
                    %textarea
                    %p Some text
```

The problem is that this only runs the **$(@).nextAll('#data').toggle("blind")** function, not the other three below it. When I was running the same coffeescript without the **$(@).nextAll** code in front, all the functions were working but only for the first  on the page.

Comment: Been looking at this for a couple, and i dont think i really see anything wrong with what you did here. You are incorrectly using `.toggle()`, it doesn't take a string like that (`"blind"`) - did you mean to toggle class? Otherwise if ur just toggling visibility you can just leave it as `.toggle()`. Check the docs. But if there really is still issue, set up a quick http://jsfiddle.net/ to test it. I used http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js to check your coffeescript compile.

Comment: Can I see your html structure please (the relevant parts)?

Comment: That should work as long as your HTML structure is correct (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RMHFu/). However, using `nextAll` with an ID selector is odd and suggests that you might have duplicate `id` attributes (which is invalid and will cause problems).

Comment: @infensus - Thanks, just added the HTML structure.

Comment: @muistooshort duplicate id attributes could be the case--what's a better way of handling this, then? Put a unique id on each <h2>?

Comment: Use classes and containment instead. If you can update that jsfiddle with the HTML (not HAML, I find HAML to be an incomprehensible mess) I can show you how to do it.

Comment: I have a feeling the html structure is not right for using nextAll in all those places but it is hard to see with that HAML

Comment: @infensus: I think I agree (on all counts), there are duplicate `id`s and `#datacontainer` is not a sibling.

Comment: Many thanks, infensus and muistooshort--it **was** an HTML issue. I had assumed it was my amateurish coffeescript that was the issue. Fixing it now... will post my solution to this later (and clean up that haml with HTML, so it'll be clearer what I was doing wrong).

Comment: @sic1 Thanks! Just FYI--jQueryUI allows for strings like "blind" to be passed to toggle(): http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/. I probably should have specified I was using jQueryUI in the context of the question though, so it's my fault for that confusion.